# client stop producing or consuming messages when in one container "rabbitmqctl stop_app" out of three rabbitmq containers are running?

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

I am running three rabbitmq pods in kubernetes.
And then I am running java performance client which can produce and consume messages.
If I go inside any one of the pod container and do "rabbitmqctl stop_app" then client will not produce any data or consumer data.

After I do "rabbitmqctl start_app" then again data resumes producing and consuming.

what could be the reason behind this.

But I was expecting if one of the server is stooped in one container out of three pods, client should still be able to produce and consume without interruption.